# Problem with IE combobox "type", my code change the value but does not update the content in the page

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select one option inside a combobox in the process to get a final production, the code is to long to post it all in here, so I will post the part I'm having problem with and if needed any extra detail just ask.

This code is changing the value of the combobox but is not loading the table witch have the value Im looking for, its loading the first one in the line.

Set e = IE.document.getElementById("inverterOption")

```
Dim o
For Each o In e.Options
    If o.Value = sninversor.Value Then
        o.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

[image]
[image]

SOLUTION:

```
Set e = IE.document.getElementById("inverterOption")

Dim o
For Each o In e.Options
    If o.Value = "'" & sninversor.Value & "'" Then
        o.Focus
        o.Selected = True
        e.FireEvent ("onchange")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the html and there is onchange event attached to "inverterOption" control

that fire a function called selectInvertor() ,

so to simulate this try using this code

```
Set e = IE.document.getElementById("inverterOption")
Dim o
For Each o In e.Options
    If o.Value = sninversor.Value Then
    o.Focus
    o.Selected = True
    o.FireEvent ("onchange")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for taking your time to help me, I have tried your code, but it seems like nothing has changed, the code end with no errors, I see your point, it need to call that function to update the page.

Comment: Thanks, I found a way to run the event with your sugestion, will post the result up there!

Comment: You welcome. but if you found a better solution then i suggest that you share the code with us so some one with the same problem will benefit .